# Azure functions interface instantiation error

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm working on an azure functions project. To enforce "correctness" I have created an interface that is auto generated that is applied to the main function class. The idea is that this ensures that the set of functions available is complete and correctly declared.

An example from the interface:

```
  public interface IFrontEndProvider
  {
      [Function("GetGrades")]
      public Task<IActionResult> GetGrades([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "{Backend}/GetGrades")] HttpRequest req, string backend, string username);
}
```

implementing class

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetGrades(HttpRequest req, string backend, string username)
 {
    
     return new OkObjectResult(10);
 
 }
```

In this setting the azure function host on my local machine starts up correctly and lists the available functions.., But when I call the function I get

> Function 'GetGrades', Invocation id
> '440edb81-366c-408f-95d8-e304a9738d7b': An exception was thrown by the
> invocation. [2024-02-12T16:03:19.277Z] Result: Function 'GetGrades',
> Invocation id '440edb81-366c-408f-95d8-e304a9738d7b': An exception was
> thrown by the invocation. Exception: System.InvalidOperationException:
> Instances of abstract classes cannot be created.

It seems it tries to create an instance of the interface and not the implementation. When I move the Function attribute to the implementing class everything works again.

Is this fixable? How do I tell the azure function host to use the implementing class.

I tried adding an abstract class in between, but same error.

**Extra clarification after first reponse to this question:**

I am trying to autogenerate the interface with attributes.
That way people implementing only need to concern about logic and not set routes, security, verbs, functionnames and al the other trappings of azure functions.
I know how an interface works, but I wanted to know if there is a way to tell the framework to look for the implementing class. Using reflection it is certainly possible to detect and find implementations of an interface. But he framework does not seem to do that. I hoped that there was something like an AddScoped dep injection function, where I can tell it to use an implementation of the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why it fails

When a Azure Functions app starts, it looks for anything that has the `[Function]` attribute on it, and tries to instantiate that type.

In your case, the attribute is on the Interface. The Functions App doesn't have any way of knowing it should instantiate your implementation class. It just tries to instantiate whatever has the attribute, which is your Interface, which isn't allowed.

(it says "Instances of abstract classes cannot be created" because an interface is similar to an abstract class. And remembering that an abstract class isn't a fully implemented class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)

### How to fix it

It's great that you're trying to use a pattern of having an Interface. If you really want to do that, you need to think differently with an Azure Function.

Instead, consider moving all your actual logic into something like a Service class. Which *can* have an interface.

So your current example of `GetGrades` might end up like this:

```cs
public interface IGradesProvider
{
    Task<GradeResult> GetGrades(string backend, string username);
}
```

Which would be implemented in a class:

```cs
public class GradesProvider : IGradesProvider
{
    public Task<GradeResult> GetGrades(string backend, string username)
    {
        return new GradeResult(10);
    }
}
```

And finally there's a concrete Endpoint class for your actual Azure Function:

```cs
public class FrontEndProvider
{
    private readonly IGradesProvider _gradesProvider;

    public FrontEndProvider(IGradesProvider gradesProvider)
    {
        _gradesProvider = gradesProvider;
    }

    [Function("GetGrades")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetGrades([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "{Backend}/GetGrades")] HttpRequest req, string backend, string username)
    {
        try
        {
            GradeResult grades = await _gradesProvider.GetGrades(backend, username);
            IActionResult result = // TODO: Convert GradeResult to ActionResult.
            return result;
        }
        catch //TODO
        {
            // Return failure code
        }
    }
}
```

### How this works

Your Azure Function Endpoint only knows about the `IGradesProvider` Interface. You would then add your `GradesProvider` implementation class into the Dependency Injection config of the Azure Function, so that the right implementation is added.

### Further thinking: consider where Interfaces are really needed

As you can probably see above, the Interface isn't really gaining you anything. You probably always want the same Service class implementation.

I think you're *probably* using an Interface so you can change the implementation, perhaps to make unit testing easier? In that case, typically your `GradesProvider` class would have logic that never changes. Instead, you would have Interfaces for what `GradesProvider` depends on. For example:

```cs
public interface IGradeDatabase
{
    Task<Grade> GetGradeForUser(string userId);
}

public interface IUserDatabase
{
    Task<User> GetUser(string userId);
}
```

```cs
public class GradesProvider : IGradesProvider
{
    private readonly IGradeDatabase _gradeDatabase;
    private readonly IUserDatabase _userDatabase;

    public GradesProvider(IGradeDatabase gradeDatabase, IUserDatabase userDatabase)
    {
        _gradeDatabase = gradeDatabase;
        _userDatabase = userDatabase;
    }

    public await Task<GradeResult> GetGrades(string backend, string username)
    {
        var user = await _userDatabase.GetUser(username);
        var grade = await _gradeDatabase.GetGradeForUser(username);

        GradeResult result = CreateGradeResultForUser(user, grade);

        return result;
    }

    private GradeResult CreateGradeResultForUser(User user, Grade grade)
    {
        // TODO: Some complex business logic.
    }
}
```

You can see that the `GradesProvider` class contains your actual business logic, which should never change. But perhaps the *database* implementations, which it uses, might change. So they have interfaces.

## Edit based on question clarification

You're wanting to have different "backend" implementations for a given API structure.

The Azure Function should *definitely* be a concrete class, I believe. It would then take a dependency, which is a Factory.

```cs
public interface IBackendFactory
{
    IGradesProvider CreateBackend(string backend);
}
```

```cs
public class FrontEndProvider
{
    private readonly IBackendFactory _backendFactory;

    public FrontEndProvider(IBackendFactory backendFactory)
    {
        _backendFactory = backendFactory;
    }

    [Function("GetGrades")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetGrades([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "{Backend}/GetGrades")] HttpRequest req, string backend, string username)
    {
        IGradesProvider backendService = GetBackendImplementation(backend);

        GradeResult grades = await backendService.GetGrades(username);
        
        IActionResult result = // TODO: Convert GradeResult to ActionResult.
        return result;
    }

    // This function is likely used by many of your endpoints.
    private IGradesProvider GetBackendImplementation(string backend)
    {
        return _backendFactory.CreateBackend(backend);
    }
}
```

Whoever is implementing your logic can now just implement their own version of an `IBackendFactory` to the dependency injection.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was trying to autogenerate the interface with attributes. This way people implementing only need to concern about logic and not set routes, security, verbs, functionnames and al the other trappings of azure functions. I know how an interface works, but I wanted to know if there is a way to tell the framework to look for the implementing class. 
I'm not sure if I can mark this as an answer. The information about interfaces is generally correct, but it doesn't really adres the query. Other then saying the framework cannot to this as its build at the moment.

Comment: Ah! OK. So basically you're trying to create an interface that _anyone else_ can implement, to match the shape of your API? I don't think that's clear in your question. You might want to update it.

I'd suggest you're going about this the wrong way. You should instead consider developing pretty much what I said above: you would make a concrete Azure Functions class, and then declare a Service `interface` type. The implementors would then create their Service based on that `interface` - much like the `IGradesProvider` example I did for you. They would then add their implementation to the DI.

Comment: But the implementers would have to set azure function attributes correctly themselves in you example. And I am trying to prevent the need for that.

Comment: No, they wouldn't. The example I gave moves your service logic (I called it `GradesProvider`) into a layer that doesn't need to know about Azure at all. It doesn't use any of the Azure Function attributes. The Attributes stay in the Azure Function, which then calls the service layer class through an interface (`IGradesProvider`)

Comment: I already have providers for the "backends" using interfaces. I'm trying to enforce the attributes on the function side. The backend used is choosen based on an url parameter. I cannot assume there will not be some extra logic in the function based on what backend is called. maybe I am overthinking it. I will give it some thought.

Comment: I see yes. I'll update my answer to suggest what you could try - but it's very similar to the above, i.e. consider having your Azure Functions class as concrete class, and then inject something that can act as a factory for the backend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256872/discussion-between-andrew-b-and-zu1b).